# How can I make the browser remember login credentials for Google mobile sites?

Tags: browser, google-account, password, stock-browser

The stock browser forgets the username and password when logging into mobile versions of Google sites such as Google Search and Google Tasks. Setting *Menu* -> *Settings* -> *Privacy Settings* -> *Remember form data* and *Menu* -> *Settings* -> *Security settings* -> *Remember passwords* in the browser has no effect. Checking the "Remember me" checkbox at the sites' login forms has no effect either.  How can I get this to work?

I use a Nexus S running Android 2.3.6.

Answer (score 3):

Webpages can opt out of autofill; intended to be added security for banks and other sites requiring higher than normal security. There are ways to circumvent this in firefox, chrome and IE but I haven't figured out how to do it for android. Whats the origin of the android browser code base? That might be another place to look.

Answer (score 1):

It could possibly be due to blocking cookies. If you don't accept the cookie it will never remeber who you are.

Check the setting for:

Menu->Settings->Accept cookies

Comment: My browser is already set to accept cookies, and it remembers the login credential of other sites.

Answer (score -2):

Use an app called LoginBox. It's a browser that specialize in remembering the complete login process.

Comment: This answer might be useful if you [edit] it to add a link to the app you're recommending. Also, please confirm your relationship (if any) with this app: recommending your own app is OK on this site, as long as you're honest.